# Get primal ray in Pyscipopt

Tags: python, optimization, scip

If we are solving a linear program and the problem is unbounded, then is it possible to get a primal ray which leads to the unboundedness? I found this [pyscipopt.lp.getPrimalRay](https://imada.sdu.dk/%7Emarco/Misc/PySCIPOpt/lp_8pxi_source.html#l00396). But I did not find any examples on how to create a pyscipopt.lp object. Can someone suggest how to get a primal ray for a *pyscipopt.scip.Model* object.

An example of a model which leads to unboundedness -

```
from pyscipopt import *

model = Model("Example")
x = model.addVar("x")
y = model.addVar("y")
model.setObjective(-x -y)
model.addCons(2*x - y*y >= 0)
model.optimize()
sol = model.getBestSol()
print("x: {}".format(sol[x]))
print("y: {}".format(sol[y]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in SCIP that gives you the values of the primal ray (if one exists) called `SCIPgetPrimalRayVal` which will give you the value for a certain variable. However, that method is not yet wrapped inside `PySCIPopt`.

You can easily do this yourself though (just do the same as all the methods in `scip.pyx`) for both `SCIPgetPrimalRayVal` and `SCIPhasPrimalRay`. And then it would be great if you could create a pull request over on the PySCIPopt github to extend the interface for everyone.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some particular reason why this method has been implemented in which we get coefficients per variable? The getPrimalRay function in pyscipopt.lp seems more convenient because it gives the entire ray at once and we don't need to get all the components separately? Also, do you have any suggestions on how to call the getPrimalRay function as it needs a LP object.

Comment: The lp object is an internal data structure and the data that gets returned as its primal ray might not be what you need (extra constants, problem reduction, etc). Why not just write a small helper function that calls this method once for each variable?